# DJI Cache folder

Tags: android, logging, base64, dji-sdk

DJI app creates a Cache folder with numerous folders and logs inside each of them :

DJI Cache folder

[image]

Each of this logs seems to be base64 encoded but i did not find any way to decode them :

```html
GmcONIA9PFzHw1gpPLLPoqev3ytAH5KO3S/CJpMsylg=
35kyjVfwBJgytCi6KM5Vug==
CB+XwmswpZT7+VlBzWpx6A==
du6kb67/wfGb3Yk9k6e3WQ==
TSdR+Iv2aYrAjLOYTi2sAr+46QsUfuFBJWaX+W69ZJm2CMTJ+Cj4/Wb2ADLt9Tzf
cwgQW1UgxyVfBeSrdwXHsL3UmiAg+paghKMSHkIW1dY=
DgsncGaxfG5ShGfJS2X/GA==
mAzeFbkWBGyzJRgEWJSZYQNn44wFaguEUnqkvHVinQw=
Q6MPvlQsM0UhZmkswxFdjgdpus+9cBFiwcBPdMJUjjc=
2lfNnhNY+w/3xMaMUxJbE0YFT/wvMlSDz8Vrd5FEs18=
0bRTrSdydMkU3JQvnCwYXTKH1gs/zXY1V0rlgri8NgNTJ0QBe+Kxel2ctb4SUinKpc7gTVR75xgKwI7YVEYTQw==
```

Does anyone have a idea how to decode that ?

Answer (score 0):

What app and version are you using?
DJI encrypts almost everything nowadays, even the flightlogs are encrypted on later dji fly versions.

So some are still possible to decrypt, but you have to know what app and version you're using.

Comment: Hi, I'm using last version of DJI Pilot! I managed to decrypt the flight logs with some very cool github project but concerning any other logs cached on the filesystem, it does not seem to be the same encryption..

Comment: Good on you! 
You can get a lot out of the logs you manage to decode. I never used pilot so I dont have a clue what the other files are. I've some decoding util I can try, if you have any log you can't decode. It looks very similar to how all string are coded in the apps.

Comment: I'm trying to get the RTMP adress where video stream is sent but i could not find it in the flight logs! The flight logs are in bytes but all those other logs are encoded in byte64.. I tried to do some byte64 to ascii decoding but it didn't do any result!

Comment: An example of this log is in my post